# android camera image disapperars with orientation count 1

Tags: android, image, navigationbar

Can anyone help me with this problem? I tried setting image to the profile in navigation bar. The image disappears black when I click using rear camera? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show your codes,so that we can debug it.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it.